# How to run Java emulator in genymotion

Tags: java

I try to run an emulator in genymotion and this is what it wrote

[image]

so I try with the virtual box and that what it says:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/plgX2.png]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It tells you why it's failing in you rseconds image:

[image]

[VT-x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Intel_virtualization_.28VT-x.29) (x86 hardware-assisted virtualization technology) is required, and is either disabled (in your BIOS), or your CPU and/or motherboard doesn't support it.